# Unit test Web API controller that uses a static helper class which uses app config setting

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, unity-container

I have a situation where I have a static class that reads my application configuration file for some configuration value. When unit testing Web API controllers that make use of this static class I am getting an error about the confgiration setting being null.

I could have duplicated the value of the key in my app config for the unit test project but that seemed dirty.

Instead I have tried to abstract the dependency on app settings via a configuration interface and inject the interface using Unity. This all seems to work but I've no idea if I have done this correctly (code below).

NB: I am using FakeItEasy for mocking in unit tests.

So my question is simple - is this the correct way?

**Interface for accessing App config**

```
public interface IConfigurationReader
{
    string GetAppSetting(string key);
}

public class ConfigurationReader : IConfigurationReader
{
    public string GetAppSetting(string key)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
    }
}
```

**Add init method to static class**

```
private static IConfigurationReader _config;

public static void Init(IConfigurationReader config)
{
    _config = config;
}
```

**Register & resolve in Unity Register Types method**

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IConfigurationReader, ConfigurationReader>("Config");
HeaderHelper.Init(unityContainer.Resolve<IConfigurationReader>("Config"));
```

**In my unit test project fake interface and call static init**

```
_config = A.Fake<IConfigurationReader>();
HeaderHelper.Init(_config);
```

**In my unit test fake call to GetAppSetting**

```
A.CallTo(() => _config.GetAppSetting("AES")).Returns(AesKey);
```

Comment: Simple answer: if you have a helper class that needs access to mutable state (such as your app config), then it should not be static. Make it a normal class and pass the app config `IConfigurationReader` instance to its constructor.

Comment: @DavidArno if I make this class non static I suppose I could then abstract the helper class and mock that out as well?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It's a bit hard to wrap one's head around exactly what's going on and where, because you've boiled your code down to one specific question - which isn't how this site works best (from our [help/on-topic]: "*do I want feedback on any/all aspects of the code?*") - this question would be much more interesting if you included that whole static class, and a bit more context to show how it's used in your code - see [Simon's checklist for posting a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/23788).

Comment: [How to get the best value out of Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) is another good meta post to read. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

You can't do Dependency Injection *and* have `static` class dependencies scattered throughout your code: when you do Dependency Injection, you need to go **all the way or not at all**, else you gain the complexity and lose the benefits.

Proper DI goes like this:

1. **Register**: Set up your IoC container and register dependencies.
2. **Resolve**: Resolve *the entire application's dependency graph* - this is ONE method call.
3. **Release**: Dispose any disposables, clean up and tear down.

Your solution doesn't follow the *Resolve* step correctly, since you're calling `.Resolve` to fetch a single specific type, only to call that specific `Init` method on your static class: in all likelihood you're eventually going to need to do this in more than one place, and that's only because *you stopped injecting dependencies* at one point.

Any code that uses this `HeaderHelper` static class has a hidden dependency that isn't being injected, which means every single piece of code that uses `HeaderHelper` is *tightly coupled* with one specific implementation of that class.

Consider the below hypothetical `MyClass`; its constructor implicitly documents the type's dependencies (here `ISomeDependency`), but `DoSomething` has a dependency that *isn't* injected from the outside:

```
private readonly ISomeDependency _dependency;

public MyClass(ISomeDependency dependency)
{
    _dependency = dependency; // explicit dependency, constructor-injected
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    var foo = HeaderHelper.Foo; // HeaderHelper is a hidden dependency
    _dependency.DoSomething(foo);
}
```

There are several ways to fix this, but *which* is best for your case largely depends on context you haven't provided in your question (we know nothing of `HeaderHelper` other than it has a vague useless name that doesn't mean anything - you should really avoid "Helper" in class names).

---

#### 1. Constructor Injection

You could do exactly like you did with the static `ConfigurationManager` class, and wrap it with an interface:

```
public interface IHeaderHelper // todo: rename!!!
{
    // members
}
```

That `Init` method seems rather artificial, and wouldn't be needed if the class' constructor took an `IConfigurationReader` dependency.

```
public class HeaderHelper : IHeaderHelper // notice: NOT static
{
    private readonly IConfigurationReader _configReader;

    public HeaderHelper(IConfigurationReader configReader)
    {
        _configReader = configReader;
    }

    // members
}
```

And then every class that needs to use a `HeaderHelper` should intake an `IHeaderHelper` constructor argument, and replace the implicit dependencies to the static class with explicit dependencies to that interface, so instead of this:

```
HeaderHelper.Foobar();
```

You would have that:

```
_headerHelper.Foobar();
```

Where `_headerHelper` is a `private readonly IHeaderHelper` instance field.

---

#### 2. Ambient Context

Constructor injection is nice, but sometimes there are *cross-cutting* dependencies that are needed pretty much everywhere - it's fairly possible that configuration is one of such dependencies. Wrapping it with an interface and constructor-injecting it will work, but then you'll end up with lots of classes that intake this dependency, and when that feels like constructor-bloating, you might want to explore other possibilities.

[Mark Seemann's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2007/07/23/ambient-context/) describes an interesting pattern to address this problem: the *Ambient Context*.

This DI pattern would change this:

```
var foo = HeaderHelper.Foo();
```

Into this:

```
var foo = HeaderSettingsContext.Current.Foo();
```

The *Ambient Context* is still an implicit dependency though, and *Constructor Injection* should be preferred most of the time. But by storing the current context in thread-local storage, your tests can easily manipulate the current context, and alter what `Foo()` does in your application (e.g. hit the file system and read some XML value vs return a mocked-up value).

[This article by Adras Nemes](https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/08/29/solid-design-principles-in-net-the-dependency-inversion-principle-part-2-di-patterns/) describes more DI patterns (the article is based on Mark Seemann's work).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I did realise this was probably wrong after I took a break. I changed it exactly to as described in option 1. Thanks for taking the time to reply though I really appreciate it